# Чтение сокета средствами C++

Tags: c++, сокет, c++11

Пишу сервер на С++, отправляю ему данные вида `dhw6558d5fjf48dnbp5fps5tkze5f83n{\"gl\":\"123\"}` а получаю это и еще 5 непонятных символов.

```
Oof: dhw6558d5fjf48dnbp5fps5tkze5f83n
Content: {"gl":"123"}
����� или �jX�� бывает
```

Выполняется эта функция:

```
    static void *read(void *args){
        cout<<"Oof..."<<endl;
        int s=*((int*)args); //сокет
        char buffer[32];
        int counter=0;
        int i=0;
        while(true){
            int rc;
            memset(&buffer,0,sizeof(char)*33);
            rc=recv(s,buffer,32,0);
            if(rc<=0)
                break;
            if(i==0){
                cout<<"Oof: "<<buffer<<endl<<"Content: ";
            }else{
                cout<<buffer<<endl;
            }
            i++;
        }
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
```

Что я делаю не так или так и должно быть?

Comment: @Abyx это не имеет значения, все-равно лишние 5 байтов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переписал на вектор символов и добавление его к строке, все работает как надо, всем спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Т.к. код, записывающий в буфер не приведен, то могу предположить только следующее: пишете  в сокет без конечного нуля, а  распечатываете через "cout<<", который ожидает этот ноль. Его можно добавить на стороне, ну тогда нужно считать  объем принятых данных.
Эти лишние байты - в памяти на принимающей стороне.

P.S. Принимающий буфер слишком мал для `memset`

```
char buffer[32];
int counter=0;
```

Вот эта строка - неопределенное поведение, она имеет право обнулить counter, а может вообще ничего не сделать:

```
memset(&buffer,0,sizeof(char)*33);
```

Для массива, но не указателя, можно записать так

```
memset(&buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
```

Answer (score -2):

`cout<<buffer` ожидает что в буфере строка заканчивающаяся нулём.

Напишите `cout.write(buf, rc);`

Comment: Oof: dhw6558d5fjf48dnbp5fps5tkze5f83n
Content: {"gl":"123"}
{"gl":"123"}53�@���f�
���f�E�� `